# Update docker mountpoint

Tags: docker

I've mounted a docker-compose volume to a mounted drive

```
  geoserver:
    build: ./geoserver
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .geoserver
    links:
      - db
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 8443
    volumes:
      - ./geoserver-exts:/var/local/geoserver-exts/
      - geoserver_data:/var/local/geoserver
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`${SITE_URL}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=leresolver"

volumes:
  geo-db-data:
  le-certs:
  geoserver_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/media/base_geoserver_geoserver_data/_data'
```

But after down, rebuilding the container and fresh `up -d` the volume is still pointing to the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/base_geoserver_geoserver_data/_data` path instead of `/media/base_geoserver_geoserver_data/_data`. (And taking space there)

sudo docker volume inspect base_geoserver_geoserver_data

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-01-27T17:08:44Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "base_geoserver",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "geoserver_data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/base_geoserver_geoserver_data/_data",
        "Name": "base_geoserver_geoserver_data",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/media/base_geoserver_geoserver_data/_data",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

How can I force refreshing the mount point path? And writing data to my /media volume?

Comment: Any particular reason to use a Docker named volume here, rather than the simpler Docker-native bind-mount syntax?  Is the `/var/lib/docker/volumes/...` directory actually different from the `/media/...` directory; if you create a file in one, does it appear in the other, and if you create a large file, what changes can you observe via df(1)?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will just mount the directory. Thought about the named volumes because of file permissions. But can handle that